# Java: Multibyte string length

Tags: java

I have a method which prints "header text" for command line programs, much like the syntax of Markdown:

```
1. =======================
2. This is a header string
3. =======================
```

This method takes a char `c` for lines 1 and 3 and repeats it `n` times based on the length of `s`.

`String.length()` works fine with the English alphabet, but how can I find the length (the visual length, that is) of a string containing foreign multibyte characters like "Å" and "Ç"?

Comment: Perhaps you're not reading the string in the correct encoding

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`String.length` will be fine for those sorts of characters, as Java strings work in UTF-16, which is sufficient to represent the vast majority of characters in common use (Latin, Greek, Arabic, Hebrew, Chinese, Thai, Devanagari, ...).

If you might need to deal with characters above U+FFFF then you need to use `codePointCount` instead of `length` to cope with surrogate pairs.

Comment: `s.length()` gives me a value of `2` if `s` is "Ø". I want this to be `1`. And I believe you might get a different value depending on the file encoding you compile the program with.

Comment: @josocblaugrana: I cannot confirm that. I tried running the following program and it printed 1: public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 System.out.println("Ø".length());
    }
}

Comment: @ReyCharles: On my end, running `System.out.println("Ø".length())` (and nothing else) returns a value of `2`… For the record, I am using a Mac.

Comment: @josocblaugrana clearly the encoding you tell the compiler to use must match the encoding of the Java source files, in the same way that you have to pass the right encoding to an `InputStreamReader` when you're reading a text file.  If your `.java` file is in UTF-8 but your compiler reads it as if it were ISO-8859-1 or MacRoman then it will see that string literal as `"\u00c3\u0098"` instead of `"\u00D8"`.

Comment: The other (less likely) reason is to do with normalization.  In simple terms, Unicode allows you to represent an accented character as a single character, or as the plain un-accented form followed by a "combining mark".  You can use [`java.text.Normalizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) to convert between them.

Comment: @IanRoberts: Right. I am using this method in my homework. Say I could not ask my teacher which platform/encoding he will use to test my program, is there no way to get an accurate length regardless of this issue?

Comment: If you can't be sure what encoding your compiler will be set to then you'll have to use Unicode escapes in the source code (i.e. say `"\u00D8"` instead of `"Ø"`).  You can automate this using the `native2ascii` tool.

Answer (score 3):

`String.length()` is fine for most [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) characters including `Å` and `Ç`.

A [Java string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) is [`utf-16`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) encoded where each  `Character` takes up `2` or `4` bytes.

[*Supplementary characters*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) denotes the characters taking `4` bytes and is implemented by *pairing* two characters, in which case the `codePointCount` operation must be used instead of `length`.

Characters  though most certainly exist in the standard unicode specification.

Comment: Lol no. In utf16 each character takes 2 or 4 bytes.

Comment: @RokKralj, which is exactly what I was trying to say. Good that you spotted that it wasn't clear enough